# Vb.net structure as process parameter

Tags: vb.net, process, structure

I have a project where i need to call an process which in turn will call a library function and this function needed to pass as a structure. What i want is something like this:

```
   Structure struct1
    Dim field1 As String
    Dim field2 As Double
End Structure

  With process
        With .StartInfo
             .Arguments() = "/Payroll" & _
             ."/wh" & struct1
             .WorkingDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
             .FileName = "VCWin32Tools.exe"
        end with
         .Start()
        .WaitForExit()
        .Close()
  end with
```

Note:
In actual project it contains a lot of fields, i don't know how can i pass it or is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an object to a new process.  Whatever you put in the `Arguments` property must be something that you could type at the commandline.  The application will receive that data as commandline arguments so it must be strings and only strings.  If you were to start this process from a console window, what would you type?  That's what you need to put in the `FileName` and `Arguments` properties.